# Forms that offer option inputs from sql table

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

I currently have a register closing site in use that allows my guys to enter their tips. When I get a new employee though, I have to add them to the database, add their name to the html page that asks for the tip amounts (sometimes for multiple stores/pages), add their name to the php page that submits the values to the database, and I have to add their names to all of the pages that I use for payroll/accounting/taxes.

I was trying to come up with a form that has option inputs using options populated from the "active employee" table, so I only have to enter them there. I have that part working!!

I then wanted to put a box beside the option box that lets them type in the amount of tips each person received.

I'm having issues with that part.

So far I have this, which gives me 5 option inputs with values from the database. I can't figure out the input box for the amounts after though.

```
<?php

require_once 'loginemployees.php';
$conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);


$res=$conn->query("select Name from Status");


    echo "<html>";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<select name='id'>";

    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {

                  unset($id, $name);
                  $id = $row['id'];
                 $name = $row['Name']; 
                  echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';

}

    echo "</select>";
    echo "Tips: $ <input type="text" name="lname">";  


    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";

echo "<br><br>";

$res=$conn->query("select Name from Status");


    echo "<html>";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<select name='id'>";

    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {

                  unset($id, $name);
                  $id = $row['id'];
                 $name = $row['Name']; 
                  echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';

}

    echo "</select>";
    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";

echo "<br><br>";



$res=$conn->query("select Name from Status");


    echo "<html>";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<select name='id'>";

    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {

                  unset($id, $name);
                  $id = $row['id'];
                 $name = $row['Name']; 
                  echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';

}

    echo "</select>";
    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";


echo "<br><br>";










$res=$conn->query("select Name from Status");


    echo "<html>";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<select name='id'>";

    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {

                  unset($id, $name);
                  $id = $row['id'];
                 $name = $row['Name']; 
                  echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';

}

    echo "</select>";
    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";









echo "<br><br>";





$res=$conn->query("select Name from Status");


    echo "<html>";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<select name='id'>";

    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {

                  unset($id, $name);
                  $id = $row['id'];
                 $name = $row['Name']; 
                  echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';

}

    echo "</select>";
    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first of all: That's a lot of unnessesary code! You can shorten it completely like this:

```
<?php

require_once 'loginemployees.php';
$conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);

/* Put your select element in variable.
   Save the values in an array (id).
   */
$select = "<select name='id[]'>";

echo "<!DOCTYPE HTML>";
echo "<html lang='en'>";
echo "<head><meta charset='utf-8'></head>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<form method='POST' action='your_form_handler.php' accept-charset='utf-8'>";

$res=$conn->query("SELECT Name FROM Status");

while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    unset($id, $name);
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['Name'];

    $select .= '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
}

$select .= "</select>";

/* Same here: Save the input values in an array (lname) */
$select .= "Tips: $ <input type='text' name='lname[]'>";
$select .= "<br/><br/>";

/* If you need more forms, just change the number here */
$numberOfForms = 5;

for($i = 0; $i < $numberOfForms; $i++){
    echo $select;
}

echo "<input type='submit' value='submit'>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";

?>
```

Now, in your backend when you submit the form, you can simply loop through the arrays:

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['lname'])){

    for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['id']); $i++){

        /* This will just display whatever is filled in. Instead you should save it in a database or something */
        echo "User with id: ". $_POST['id'][$i] ." had as tip: ". $_POST['lname'][$i] ."<br/>";
    }
}

?>
```

Keep in mind that I haven't tested this because I don't have your database here but it should work just fine.